# Menu PHP SQL always puts <ul> in the code

Tags: php, html

First, I am trying to get my HTML Menu data echoed from my database. That part works fine. The problem is, when I use the following code, it always puts

```
<ul></ul>
```

after every menu item. But I only want the `<ul>` elements if there actually is a submenu.

```
foreach($items as $item) {
    if($item['parent_id'] == 0) {
        echo "<li><a href='#'>".$item['menu']."</a>";
        $id = $item['id'];
        sub($items, $id);
        echo "</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";

function sub($items, $id) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($items as $item) {
        if($item['parent_id'] == $id) {
            echo "<li><a href='#'>".$item['menu']."</a>";
            sub($items, $item['id']);
            echo "</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

?>
```

This is the HTML Result:

```
<li><a href='#'>united states</a><ul>
<li><a href='#'>texas</a><ul></ul></li
<li><a href='#'>montana</a><ul></ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>washington</a><ul></ul></li></ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>india</a><ul>
<li><a href='#'>Maharashtra</a><ul></ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>Bihar</a><ul></ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>karnataka</a><ul>
<li><a href='#'>bangalore</a><ul></ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>belgaum</a><ul></ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>mysore</a><ul>
<li><a href='#'>brindavan</a><ul></ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>mysore palace</a><ul></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>russia</a><ul>
<li><a href='#'>moscow</a><ul></ul></li></ul></li>
<li><a href='#'>britan</a><ul></ul></li></ul>
```

You can see it puts the

```
<ul></ul>
```

every time after the menu item. How do i get rid of it?

Comment: Is there a missing closing bracket at the end of your PHP code? Please format your code - it is hard to read.

Comment: Sorry for that, thats really what it is spitting out, and the bracket, its there in the code, just forgot to copy, sorry :)

Comment: It's probably what @l0rkaY says. On a side note, it looks like you are repeating yourself, you should be able to achieve the same result only by using the `sub` function.

Answer (score 1):

In function sub() try to check $items

```
If count($items) > 0 then echo <ul>, run foreach and echo </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
function sub($items, $id) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($items as $item) {
        if($item['parent_id'] == $id) {
            echo "<li><a href='#'>".$item['menu']."</a>";
            sub($items, $item['id']);
            echo "</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

To

```
function sub($items, $id) {

    if($this->hasChildren($items, $id)){
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($items as $item) {
            if($item['parent_id'] == $id) {
                echo "<li><a href='#'>".$item['menu']."</a>";
                sub($items, $item['id']);
                echo "</li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

function hasChildren(array $array, $parent_id)
{
   foreach($array as $item)
   {
      if($item['parent_id'] === $parent_id) return true;
   }

   return false;
}
```

You just need to make sure you actually have items by counting them before you loop through them. At the moment, if you don't have any `$items`, you still write `<ul></ul>`.

Adding a `count` before you echo `<ul>` means you only output `<ul>` and perform the loop IF you have at least 1 item.

Comment: It still puts them there, but thats logic, because $items is still above zero.. because $items are all the items.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see, completely missed that bit! In that case, you will need another function, probably called `hasChildren()` which accepts all the items, and the parent ID you want to find children for. In the function, loop through each item and if the parent ID has been found, return true. That way you know you can safely write the `<ul>` tags - because there is at least one item to return. I hope this helps.

Comment: It just stops after the first submenu. It doesnt display the submenu, and every menu after that is also not displayed..